# Polymer JS - Parametric neon-animation config

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component, neon-animation

I have a component - floating digit that animates from bottom to top.
And this code is working perfectly fine:

```
<dom-module id="floating-digit">


<style>
    span.increment {
      display: none;
      font-size: 12px;
      font-weight: normal;
      position: absolute;
      right: -10px;
      top: 1.25em;
    }
  </style>

  <template>
    <span id="floater" class="increment">+[[digit]]</span>
  </template>

</dom-module>


<script>
  Polymer({
    is: "floating-digit",
    behaviors: [Polymer.NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior],
    properties: {
      digit: {
        type: String,
        value: "",
        observer: '_animateDigit'
      },
      transformFrom: {
        type: String,
        value: "translateY(0)"
      },
      transformTo: {
        type: String,
        value: "translateY(-100%)"
      },
      animationConfig: {
        value: function () {
          return {
            'animate': [
              {
                name: 'fade-in-animation',
                node: this.$.floater,
                timing: {duration: 100}
              },
              {
                name: 'transform-animation',
                node: this.$.floater,
                transformFrom: "translateY(0)",
                transformTo: "translateY(-100%)",
                timing: {duration: 1500}
              },
              {
                name: 'fade-out-animation',
                node: this.$.floater,
                timing: {duration: 2000, delay: 2000}
              },

            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    listeners: {
      'neon-animation-finish': '_onNeonAnimationFinish'
    },
    _animateDigit: function _animateDigit() {
      this.$.floater.style.display = "inline";
      this.playAnimation('animate');

    },
    _onNeonAnimationFinish: function _onNeonAnimationFinish() {
      this.$.floater.style.display = 'none';
    },
  })
</script>
```

But there are several places on my app where I want to use this component with different transformFrom and transformTo values.

That is why I added to my `floating-digit` properties `transformTo` and `transformFrom`, so I can parametrize them when I want those values to be different than default:

```
<floating-digit id="floating-0" transform-from="translateY(-20%)" transform-to="translateY(-80%)" digit="[[someNumber]]"></floating-digit>
```

I have changed animationConfig this way (only changed excerpt):

```
{
 name: 'transform-animation',
 node: this.$.floater,
 transformFrom: this.transformFrom,
 transformTo: this.transformTo,
 timing: {duration: 1500}
},
```

But it does not work. This function seems not to have access to all those properties defined in element.

`console.log(this)` inside function returning animationConfig object value properly identifies `this` as desired instance of `<floating-digit>`. Unfortunately, without properties that can be used for parametrizing configuration of animations. They remain undefined.

Any of you possibly have an idea how to access those parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested I have found solution. Unfortunately this solution does not use Polymer to grab those parameters.

I am using native web API to do this:
My animationConfig looks that way:

```
  animationConfig: {
    value: function () {
      let transformFrom = this.attributes.getNamedItem('transform-from') ? this.attributes.getNamedItem('transform-from').textContent : "translateY(0)";
      let transformTo = this.attributes.getNamedItem('transform-to') ? this.attributes.getNamedItem('transform-to').textContent : "translateY(-100%)";
      return {
        'animate': [
          {
            name: 'fade-in-animation',
            node: this.$.floater,
            timing: {duration: 100}
          },
          {
            name: 'transform-animation',
            node: this.$.floater,
            transformFrom: transformFrom,
            transformTo: transformTo,
            timing: {duration: 1500}
          },
          {
            name: 'fade-out-animation',
            node: this.$.floater,
            timing: {duration: 2000, delay: 2000}
          },
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

And I am calling this same way as before:

```
<floating-digit id="floating-0" transform-from="translateY(-20%)" transform-to="translateY(-70%)" digit="5"></floating-digit>
```

If anyone have idea why this does not work properly, you are more than invited to share your solution.